# Rails rack gem conflicting when trying a Facebook Oauth2 demo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, rubygems, oauth, rack

When I run rake db:migrate for this code http://github.com/jonastryggvi/facebook-rails, I obtain :

```
can't activate rack (~> 1.2.1, runtime) for ["faraday-0.5.1"], already activated rack-1.0.1 for ["actionpack-2.3.5", "rails-2.3.5"]
```

This, of course, prevent the Oauth2 gem from loading, and I cannot run the demo. I tried extracting the gems locally in vendor/gems through rake gems:unpack:dependencies, but it crashes with

```
rake gems:unpack:dependencies --trace
(in /jonastryggvi-facebook-rails-b6b043c)
** Invoke gems:unpack:dependencies (first_time)
** Invoke gems:install (first_time)
** Invoke gems:base (first_time)
** Execute gems:base
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute gems:install
** Execute gems:unpack:dependencies
rake aborted!
undefined method `version' for nil:NilClass
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:52:in `method_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:294:in `unpack_command'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:249:in `unpack'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:248:in `chdir'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:248:in `unpack'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:255:in `unpack'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:255:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:255:in `unpack'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/gems.rake:47
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/gems.rake:47:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/gems.rake:47
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

I also tried extracting them manually through gem unpack rack -v=1.0.1, which worked, (it's in vendor/gems, but I still get the same errors. I also got the same error on my Windows machine, than on my Linux/Ubuntu machine.

Thanks for the help you can give me.

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.5, 2.3.3, 2.3.2, 2.2.2)
actionpack (2.3.5, 2.3.3, 2.3.2, 2.2.2)
activerecord (2.3.5, 2.3.3, 2.3.2, 2.2.2)
activeresource (2.3.5, 2.3.3, 2.3.2, 2.2.2)
activesupport (2.3.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.3, 2.3.2, 2.2.2)
addressable (2.2.2)
adzap-ar_mailer (2.1.5)
chronic (0.2.3)
faraday (0.5.1)
fcgi (0.8.7)
hoe (2.3.3)
i18n (0.1.0)
json_pure (1.1.9)
linecache (0.43)
memcache-client (1.7.5)
multi_json (0.0.4)
multipart-post (1.0.1)
mysql (2.7)
net-scp (1.0.2)
net-ssh (2.0.15)
newrelic_rpm (2.9.4)
nkallen-cache-money (0.2.5)
oauth2 (0.1.0)
packet (0.1.15)
rack (1.2.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.0)
rails (2.3.5, 2.3.3, 2.3.2, 2.2.2)
rake (0.8.7, 0.8.3)
RedCloth (4.1.9)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.3)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.4)
rubyforge (2.0.3)
rubygems-update (1.3.7, 1.3.5)
sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last faraday version ( >= 0.5.0 ) is not compatible to Rack 1.0.1 and Rails 2.3.5 is not compatible to rack >= 1.0.1

You have two choice

Fix faraday gem to 0.4.9 . This gem is compatible to Rails 2.3.5. Or upgrade your application to Rails 2.3.9 compatible to rack 1.1.0.

Comment: Merci, it help me fix it. I had to use Faraday version 0.4.6! I appreciate it much!